# PHP Login script returns only one condition

Tags: php

/*  When I test the login page, I enter the info for the user account that I manually set up in phpMyAdmin, but it keeps returning the error, "username was not found."*/

```
<?php
 session_start();
  include_once '../../config/dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location:http://www.google.com");
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
  $upass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);
  $query= "SELECT email, pass from  users WHERE email='$email' and pass  =$upass'";
  $result= mysqli_query($con,$query);

if($result)
   {
      echo "user found";
   }
 else
{
    echo "user was not found";
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a quote in your query

Comment: Since you're using `mysqli` you should use a prepared query. That will solve problems like this, and also avoid SQL-injection.

Comment: Another problem: `$result` just tells whether your query was successful or got an error. It doesn't report whether any rows were found. You need to call `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or `mysqli_num_rows` to find out if anything was found.

Comment: The `else` clause should have `echo mysqli_error($con)` to show the reason why it failed.

Comment: Side tip: retrieve something other than email and password. You already have the data (email, password)  from user input in the form. And, as Barmar said, you need to fetch rows from the resultset. You can't use $result in the conditional.

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar I added the following to the if condition : if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)

Answer (score 0):

Missing quote:

```
$query= "SELECT email, pass from  users WHERE email='$email' and pass  =$upass'";
```

should be:

```
$query= "SELECT email, pass from  users WHERE email='$email' and pass  = '$upass'";
```

quote was added right before `$upass`